# Echoing column data from each row, using mysqli loop, breaking after 15 results

Tags: arrays, loops, mysqli, echo, break

I'm trying to gather data from my SQL database so I can make a custom defined table in html and insert each cell (from each row) data from a column.

I would like to input the result as a simple echo command (see example). I previously tried to do this with $i=0, then using $i++ to increment within the loop. Now when I echo the displayed data just prints 'Array'. My logic is under question so I need a second (sounder) opinion.

Connection then:

```
<?php
$query  = "SELECT * ";
$query .= "FROM Form ";
$query .= "ORDER BY ID DESC";
$all = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
if (!$all) {
  die("Database trouble.");

}
?>   
<?php
while($row = $all->fetch_assoc()){
?>
```

then within each area of the html I wanted to insert something like:

```
 <?php
 echo $row['box1']->num_rows;
 ?>
```

then another entry,

```
 <?php
 echo $row['box1']->num_rows;
 ?>
```

etc.

```
 <?php
 }
 ?>
```

then free results and stop the connection. I can echo all the data from the table, but finding it hard to echo individual data without a long unclear script. This seems a basic requirement when echoing data, but haven't found a clear example anywhere.
Ideally I want a clean code that can be manipulated with variables from a combobox style drop down list.
 Thanks in advance.

Comment: Using `$row['box1']->num_rows` seems to make no sense here. `$row` is a record from your database and `box1` the value from one column inside that record. No reason why that should have a `num_rows` property.

Comment: I wanted to limit the result to one individual string, but in total I want to loop a list of approximately 15 data points. 'box1' is the column data from each row, how can I tell it to move onto the next row without complex code? Its pretty clear I'm a relative novice to coding in mysqli, previously I was reliant on mysql.

Comment: Whether you use MySQL or MySQLi functions should not matter much in regard to the actual script logic.